fixest - sandwich compatibility in R to estimate bootstrap standard errors in feols
The fixest package documentation says that it is compatible with sandwich "Compatibility with sandwich package The VCOVs from sandwich can be used with feols, feglm and fepois estimations" (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/fixest.pdf) and the vignette also shows the following example (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html#24_Other_types_of_VCOVs):
library(fixest)
library(sandwich)
data(base_did)
feols(y ~ x1 | id, base_did, vcov = function(x) sandwich::vcovHC(x, type = "HC1"))

However, the vcovBS() function gives error with some "types", e.g.
data(mtcars)
fit1<- feols(mpg ~ wt | am, data = mtcars,
            vcov = function(x) sandwich::vcovBS(x, type = "webb"))

Error in match.arg(tolower(type), c("xy", "jackknife", "fractional")) : 
  'arg' should be one of “xy”, “jackknife”, “fractional”

vcovBS works as expected with lm and coeftest, so I guess there is a compatibility problem between fixest and sandwich.
library(lmtest)
fit<- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

fit_se<- coeftest(fit, vcov = sandwich::vcovBS, type = "webb")

Doing it in two steps with coeftest delivers the same error as doing it inside the feols function.
Question: how do you estimate Webb (or any other type, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sandwich/versions/3.0-2/topics/vcovBS) with a feols object?

Obviously, "compatibility" doesn't necessarily mean full compatibility—there is no vcovBS.fixest method. "fixest" objects do not inherit from anything else,
> feols_fit <- feols(y ~ x1 | id, base_did)
> class(feols_fit)
[1] "fixest"

so "fixest" objects will dispatch vcovBS.default.
As the error message suggests, in vcovBS.default you may choose just among these three:
> vcovBS.default
type <- match.arg(tolower(type), c("xy", "jackknife", "fractional"))

Whereas e.g. "lm" objects have more options:
> vcovBS.lm
...
type <- match.arg(gsub("wild-", "", tolower(type), fixed = TRUE), 
    c("xy", "jackknife", "fractional", "residual", "wild", 
        "webb", "rademacher", "mammen", "norm", "user"))

